# Why do I get all non-null's when I read a perfectly fine csv file in pandas python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a perfectly fine csv file in pandas and when I checked the head, I am see all non-null's. Why is this happening?

My CSV file:

```
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    3631    3913    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    3996    4276    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "2"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    4486    4605    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "3"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    4706    5095    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "4"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    5174    5326    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "5"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    5439    5899    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "6"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1
Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    23146   24451   .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "DCL1"; oId "AT1G01040.1";
```

My code to read the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", sep = '\t', header = None)
df.head()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns:
X.1    5  non-null values
X.2    5  non-null values
X.3    5  non-null values
X.4    5  non-null values
X.5    5  non-null values
X.6    5  non-null values
X.7    5  non-null values
X.8    5  non-null values
X.9    5  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2), object(7)
```

In addition, I'm getting this error when I run the following

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_in2, sep = '\t', header = None, engine = 'python)
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine'
```

Comment: what versions of python and pandas are you using? I cannot reproduce this error. I can read in your csv just fine.

Comment: it looks like pandas is truncating the output, the data should still be there as for your error, is that typo where you're missing the closing `'` quote mark?

Comment: The pandas seems to be the latest version and i have fixed the typo but still i can't seem to read my file. I changed the code a bit and now i can see proper row in my file but still there are these non-null's `5  non-null values
gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "ANAC001"; oId "AT1G01010.1"; nearest_ref "AT1G01010.1"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS1"; p_id "P1";    5  non-null values`

Comment: I have had success using pd.read_table for reading tab delimited data.